# Problem with Apache2 connecting to database

Tags: apache2

I installed Apache2
from this post: http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts-lamp

Then I want to put my website files and database
I copied website files and put it on www path.

Then, create database and import it [database.sql]

When I enter website [http://localhost/website]
Display [error]

My Config File:

```
<pre> 
// Information 
$server = "localhost"; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = "root"; 
$dbname = "wecg"; 

// Connect 

$connectdb = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die("error"); 
$selectdb = mysql_select_db($dbname,$connectdb) or die("error");  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this needs to be moved, but there is two things here.

PHP's mysql_* functions are depreciated, so you should be using PDO now which is really simple to use.

The other thing we need is the errors output. From what you have above you need to change the code to the following, (do it for both)

```
... or die(mysql_error());
```

instead of just saying error it will tell you/us the exact issue.

Comment: Index display this error " No database selected"
my config db is 

$dbname = "wecg";

Comment: you need to move `$server = "localhost";` to the next line, I thought that was just an error you made while posting.